Help with this step in Calderon-Zygmund decomposition
I'm currently reading this pdf: https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1231351/FULLTEXT01.pdf On Singular Integral Operators, Marcus Vaktnäs. 
In the fourth line it says "so at least one of $\langle |f| \rangle _I$ and $\langle |f| \rangle _J$ are still greater than $\lambda$ ". This may be very dumb but I don't see how that is true? In the previous line it shows that the sum is smaller than $2\lambda$, couldn't both of them be smaller than $\lambda$?

Just consider the simple counterexample $f\equiv 1$ (i.e. $f$ is the constant function 1). Then $\langle f\rangle=\langle f\rangle_J=\langle f\rangle_I=1$. Pick any $\lambda>1$ and you'll see why the sentence "so at least one of $\langle |f|\rangle_J$ and $\langle |f|\rangle_J$
are still greater than $\lambda$" is wrong.
The correct idea of the decomposition is that each time after subdividing the intervals, you pick the subintervals such that the average of $|f|$ on this interval is still larger than $\lambda$. It is completely fine if such subintervals don't exist (for example the aforementioned constant functions), but if they do exist, then you can use the estimate in the pdf.
